# Shell script to create patch for selected files

Tags: shell, diff, patch

I have two directories `new` and `old` with almost similar directory structure as shown below with some differences.

```
old
|----1
|    |-1a.cpp
|    |-1b.cpp
|----2
|    |-2c.cpp
|----3
|    |-3a.cpp
|    |-3b.cpp
|----4
|    |-4a.cpp
|    |-4b.cpp
|----5
|    |-5a.cpp
|    |-5b.cpp

------------

new
|----1
|    |-1a.cpp
|    |-1b.cpp
|----4
|    |-4a.cpp
|----5
|    |-5a.cpp
|    |-5b.cpp
```

The directory `new` contains the modified files. But it maintains the directory structure of `old`.

How to write a shell script to generate a patch using `diff` utility of `old` and `new` directories. The `patch` should contain only the difference of only those files in `new` directory. It should not contain other files in `old` directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkpatch() {
    new=$1
    old=${1/new/old}
    patch=${1}.patch
    diff "$old" "$new" > "$patch"
}
export -f mkpatch

# cd to parent directory of old and new

find new -type f -exec bash -c 'mkpatch/{}' \;
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not fix

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: Why not? what happens?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want I think.

```
#!/bin/sh

OLD_DIR=old
NEW_DIR=new

# Make list of files, stripping off first directory in path
find "$OLD_DIR" -type f -print | cut -d/ -f2- | sort > files-old
find "$NEW_DIR" -type f -print | cut -d/ -f2- | sort > files-new

# Get files that are common
comm -1 -2 files-old files-new > files-common

# Create list of files to diff
sed "s/^/$OLD_DIR\//" files-common > files-to-diff-old
sed "s/^/$NEW_DIR\//" files-common > files-to-diff-new

# Do the diff
paste -d ' ' files-to-diff-old files-to-diff-new | xargs -n 2 diff -u

# Cleanup. Temp file handling should probably be done better by using
# mktemp to generate file names and using trap to make sure the files
# always are deleted etc. 
rm -f files-common files-new files-old files-to-diff-new files-to-diff-old
```

It is just a simple, straight forward approach using several temporarily files. You might get away with some of those if you want to.